# Unable to start workspace defined task from workspace launch configuration [VS Code]

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to create a visual studio code workspace for my node js project. One of the launch configurations calls on two task I define above it in the same `.code-workspace` file. However, only the `preLaunchTask` runs; `postDebugTask` does not. The configuration does launch but the last task is skipped.

**Error Message:**

*Task 'Stop App' can not be referenced from a launch configuration that is in a different workspace folder.*

**Launch Configuration:**

```
{
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Debug with Chrome",
   "url": "http://localhost:3000",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder:my-app}/home",
   "preLaunchTask": "Start App",
   "postDebugTask": "Stop App", //<----error
},
```

**Tasks:**

```
{
 "label": "Stop App",
 "type": "process",
 "command": [
   "${command:workbench.action.tasks.terminate}",
   "${command:workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem}"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Also encountering this same exact error with a C++ configuration in a VSCode workspace.

Comment: I ended up not using multi-root workspaces (`.code-workspace`) and back to single-folder workspaces, which bypasses the problem. But maybe this is worth opening an issue to on the VSCode repository.